# Loading multiple files to neo4j using groovy

Tags: groovy, neo4j, batch-processing

I have 30 files and each file has ~65 million entries. I am using this approach

http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/flexible-neo4j-batch-import-with-groovy/

to load them to neo4j. The syntax I am using is

```
groovy my_script.groovy /path/to/graph.db file
```

Can I load multiple files at the same time? I tried adding them one by one, but I can't load more than one file. The second one takes forever to index everything.

Is there any alternative way of doing this?

Comment: "you can't" means exactly what?  errors, exceptions, ...?  it would also help to reference the actual used script here.  and is your question actually about how to do this in parallel?  otherwise i would see no difference to `for a in *; groovy script db "$a"`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jexp/0617412dcdd644fd520b#file-import_kaggle-groovy is the script. Can't means that it takes unreasonably long to index everything. To load and index one file takes ~20min. Then to load and index second file took more than 45min.

Comment: You can iterate over a list of input files, the index is populated at shutdown. So you should add all file contents using the Batch-Inserter and then let neo create the index on shutdown. Btw. using Java over Groovy makes it much faster.

Comment: the linked script already reads two files (Paper and PaperAuthor).  if all your files are of the same column structure you can just copy the csv in one file.  and there is also http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html